# how to use a block of commands in triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-5.1

The following code works

```
CREATE
TRIGGER rebuild_course_auto_enrollment_tree_mv AFTER INSERT
ON course_auto_enrollment FOR EACH ROW  
DELETE FROM
cron_event_tasks;
```

If I add the `BEGIN` ... `END` as written in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

```
 CREATE
    TRIGGER rebuild_course_auto_enrollment_tree_mv AFTER INSERT
    ON course_auto_enrollment FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
    DELETE FROM
    cron_event_tasks;
    END;
```

This is not working, hmmmm...What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me.
I am using phpmyadmin, and it uses the `;` as the delimiter to separate queries.
Solution: change in the query window of phpmyadmin the delimiter to something else and wallah...